# .Net MVC 5 nested isinrole

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, asp.net-identity-2

Is it possible with ASP.NET C# MVC 5 (.NET 4.5.1) using Identity 2.0 to have nested `IsInRole()`.  I am doing this because I want to hide a menu element to only people in the `Admin` role and on top of that, I want to hide a link to only people in the `Developer` role.  That way, only developers can add roles.

For example:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
  <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropdown-toggle" id="adminMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Admin
              <span class="caret"></span>
          </div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
              @if(User.IsInRole("Developer"))
              {
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("RolesAdmin", "Index", "RolesAdmin")</li>
              }
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("UsersAdmin", "Index", "UsersAdmin")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("GroupsAdmin", "Index", "GroupsAdmin")</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </li>
}
```

Any Ideas?  Or am I approaching this wrong?

Thank you

Comment: This seems fine to me... is it not working as you'd expect?

Comment: That looks good to me. Is it working as you need it to?

Comment: This code wont execute for users who only have Developer role

Comment: You need to attach the "Admin" role to a "Developer" when a request is authenticated. role="Developer,Admin". Are you using FormsAuthentication?

Comment: Its not working as expected.  I extended my identity manager to incorporate groups.  I checked the table and it shows that my user is apart of both Admin and Developer roles.  The <code>ActionLink()</code> still does not show.

As for web forms, I did not select Web Forms, I selected MVC, so I dont think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code always worked, I had to log out and log back in to see the updated changes with the permissions.

I was testing this on a single account so the cookie was not getting update with the new data.

Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the responses.